# \ref, \cite, toc and list figures stopped working

Tags: overleaf

I've been working on a pdflatex document all day without any pause in Overleaf, but now it seems that \ref, \cite, toc and list figures stopped working. I hadn't added any new packages, merely was typing out sections and content. Oddly enough the list of tables are still present. Any advice? Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

% 
\usepackage{UVMThesisStyle-March2016}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mhchem}

% Figures Countes by Section
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}

% Recently Added Packages
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight
  -(1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight)
  -1in}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Multiple Bibs
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{New}{References}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[]{} 
\makeatother


% Remove number from Chapters in TOC
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname #1ignore\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\let\sectionignore\@gobbletwo
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}
\makeatother
% Center Sections
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}

%Define line spacing
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: It's going to be incredibly difficult to diagnose this from what you've given (which is not a compilable document). This isn't a preamble, frankly, that gives high confidence (e.g. not sure why you are addressing chapter numbers with some weird stuff about sections ...). My suspicion would focus on this and the `multibib` stuff, but without seeing a MWE I'm not sure. What I would do is take just those sections and see if you can get a test document working.

Comment: _[Disclaimer/Disclosure: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ You might want to try clearing the auxiliary files in your compile session: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache Also, Overleaf converts all plain text files to UTF8, so `\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}` should be removed. (You can change it to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` but that's already the default since TL2018.)

Comment: This sounds like you have an error that interrupts processing before the auxilliary files are finalized.